# Jade is adding a <p> tag for some reason

Tags: pug

My template looks like

```
      each question in instruction.questions
        article
          div.question-div
            div.question-text
              | #{question.num}.
              !=question.questionText
```

When it renders, it looks like

```
<article>
  <div class="question-div">
    <div class="question-text">36.
      <p>Since I can’t alter my nature, I guess I’ll just terrify you.</p>
    </div>
    <ol type="A">
      <li>Since I can’t alter my nature, I guess I’ll just terrify you.</li>
      <li>Since I can't alter my nature</li>
      <li>guess I’ll just terrify you.</li>
      <li>none of the choices</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="answer-div"><small>answer</small></div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</article>
```

I'm not sure why it's adding the extra `<p>` tag in the `question-text` div. Any thoughts? I want it to be unbuffered since there's HTML in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text with the question number. try this:

```
div.question-text
    | #{question.num}. !=question.questionText
```

or you can try this:

```
div.question-text
    | #{question.num}.
    | !=question.questionText
```

i never used !=... but i think you`re using the jade to auto generate your layout in client side... you also can try this:

```
div.question-text
    | #{question.num}.=question.questionText
```

But as you`re using in client side without "!" i think will not work...

hope one of this tips can help you.

The problem is Jade was not identifying the

```
    !=question.questionText
```

as same line...